# Calculate cosine similarity from specific pages of annual reports

Tags: r, similarity, information-extraction, trigonometry

I want to extract specific pages of two annual reports. After, I want to calculate the cosine similarity between these specific pages of two annual reports.

I've been recently using R. So basically, I have none knowledge of R. Maybe this is the reason why I am stuck ?

I try to extract the annual report of BASF:

```
library(tabulizer)

site <- "https://www.basf.com/cz/documents/BASF_Report_2018.pdf"

extract text from a pdf:

text <- extract_text("BASF_Report_2018.pdf")

cat(text)
```

Then I try to slip per sentence like this:

```
strsplit(text, "\n")
```

and then I did the same for the second annual report. After this, I am stuck.
I know to calculate the cosine similarity we have to use this code:

```
feature <- c('feat.1', 'feat.2')

observation <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')

mRaw <- matrix(c(1,2,2,1.5,1.5,-1.5,-2,-1,-2, 1.5),nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE)

mOr <- matrix(c(0.5,1,1,0.5,0.5,-1,-0.5,-0.5,0,0.5),nrow = 5, byrow = TRUE)

dimnames(mRaw) <- list(observation, feature)

dimnames(mOr) <- list(observation, feature)

mDevOr <- mRaw - mOr

normDevOr <- apply(mDevOr, 1, function(x) {sqrt(sum(x^2))})

mUnit <- mDevOr / normDevOr

mDevSim <- mUnit %*% t(mUnit)

mDegrees <- round(acos(mDevSim) * 180 / pi,0)

mDegrees

Cos(mDegrees)
```

But how from what I extract, could I put in a way to calculate the cosine similarity ?

Comment: you will need to transform each document into a numeric vector (e.g. of word counts) in order to calculate distance/similarity metrics. first get the vocab across both docs, then fill a 2-row doc-term matrix and calculate your metric using one row against the other

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried many times but didn't succed to transform each document into a numeric vector. Could you please explain to me how could i do it ?